# Do I need to use Express.js at all with Apollo Server 2.0?

Tags: javascript, express, web-applications, graphql, apollo

I'm building a Node web application where students will take live classes from instructors. This means multiple user types (Students, Parents, and Instructors), Classes with registrants, and associated data (posts, questions, quiz answers, etc.) related to these classes. There's also a forum/community component that we will likely build post-MVP.

I think I'm going use GraphQL, but I'm not sure if I should use express-graphql or Apollo Server 2. It seems Apollo Server 2 ***can*** act as a standalone server. It even seems like I don't need Express at all. **Is this true, and is it something I should consider?**

Side Note: I'm worried that by using GraphQL and Apollo that I'll be having to reinvent a lot of wheels that would otherwise be  a library import away with an Express+REST implementation. Conversely, there is a lot of support for Express.js when looking at different packages on the internet (such as Passport.js for authentication) that makes development a lot faster.